# How to raise exception instead of returning None in Python "ConfigParser" section?

Tags: python, python-3.x, configparser

I have a problem using the [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) module.

```py
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read_dict({"foo": {}})

foo = config["foo"]
foo.getboolean("missing_field")
```

I would like my code to raise an exception if the parsed configuration is missing a required field. However, `getboolean()` returns `None` in this case instead of raising a `KeyError` as expected.

I could possibly use `foo["missing_field"]` which does raise an exception. However, in such case, I loose the boolean conversion.

I could explicitly test for `if res is None:` and throw the exception manually but I have a lot of config fields so that would be cumbersome.

Does Python provide an elegant way to force strict config parsing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`getboolean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.getboolean) on the config object directly:

```
config.getboolean("foo", "missing_field")
```

which will raise a `NoOptionError` if `missing_field` doesn't exist:

```
configparser.NoOptionError: No option 'missing_field' in section: 'foo'
```

The different behavior for `getboolean` on the proxy is because it calls the relevant getter with a default `fallback=None`. The problem is that the "regular" `get` uses a special `_UNSET` object as the default fallback and then does:

```py
if fallback is _UNSET:
    raise NoOptionError(option, section)
else:
    return fallback
```

So, as an alternative (which came up in the discussion for @Tomerikoo's answer and @chepner suggested in a comment to this answer), you can pass in `_UNSET` as the fallback value when using the section proxy. As per your original code:

```
foo.getboolean("missing_field", fallback=configparser._UNSET)
```

Comment: You can (re)set the fallback to force the exception: `foo.config("missing_field", fallback=configparser._UNSET)`.

Comment: (Oh, didn't see that Tomerikoo suggested the same thing while I was researching it.)

Comment: Both options still require to change every access in the code so I still think my class is the best solution ;D Just kidding...

Answer (score 4):

Well... @Kemp found a tweaky behaviour that solves this easily, but as I already went through the following trouble, I might as well just post it...

---

The default behavior doesn't raise an exception, but why not "fix" it according to your needs? You can create a sub-class of `ConfigParser` that only wraps `getboolean` with a check if the `option` actually exists and then returns the original `getboolean` value. I think the nice thing about this option is that you don't need to change your code at all - just change the initial `config = ...` line to use the new class:

```py
import configparser

class MyConfig(configparser.ConfigParser):
    def getboolean(self, section, option, *, raw=False, vars=None,
                   fallback=configparser_UNSET, **kwargs):
        if self.get(section, option, raw=raw, vars=vars, fallback=fallback) == fallback:
            raise configparser.NoOptionError(option, section)

        return super().getboolean(section, option, raw=raw, vars=vars, fallback=fallback)
```

Now doing:

```py
config = MyConfig()
config.read_dict({"foo": {'existing_field': '1'}})

foo = config["foo"]
print(foo.getboolean("existing_field"))
print(foo.getboolean("missing_field"))
```

Will give (truncated):

```
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
configparser.NoOptionError: No option 'missing_field' in section: 'foo'
```

As opposed to:

```
True
None
```

With the regular `configparser.ConfigParser`.

Comment: The `getboolean` implementation on `ConfigParser` already has this behaviour, it's the proxy class it returns when you access a section via the mapping protocol that (strangely) doesn't have this behaviour. *Edit: I've seen your update now and I'm intrigued as to how this works. Taking a look.*

Comment: Problem is that it will also require implementing `get()`, `getint()` and `getfloat()` which is quite cumbersome just to circumvent a poor API design. But yeah, that's a possible workaround.

Comment: Well it definitely works, though I'm not exactly sure why. One modification I would suggest is to raise `configparser.NoOptionError(option, section)` to match the behaviour of the base `ConfigParser`.

Comment: @Kemp I couldn't find `getboolean` in the `SectionProxy` class, but `get` has `fallback=None` as opposed to `fallback=_UNSET` in the `RawConfigParser`... Seems to be the problem. Under the section proxy the fallback is always None. So another possible workaround to call `foo.getboolean("missing_field", fallback=configparser._UNSET)`

Comment: @Kemp yep the above works as well... setting `fallback=_UNSET`

Comment: Ah, the proxy uses a different default fallback than the config parser, I didn't catch that. That definitely feels like a bug to me. I think in your comment you've just hit on an answer that better matches the original question than either of our actual answers :) It has the drawback of pulling in a private module variable, which can feel wrong (and your IDE will likely complain), but it is a valid answer in my opinion.

Comment: @Kemp I was going to offer you to add it in your answer as it seems more relevant. The two options are call the `config`'s `get` and pass the section, or call the `section`'s `get` and pass a `fallback`

Comment: I've added it to mine as an alternative. I think you're right that it makes sense to keep similar answers together.

Comment: @Kemp mind if I edit in to your answer some clarifications? I already started writing something up. Wouldn't want it to go to waste. Of course you can feel free to change it after

Comment: @Kemp by the way the reason why my class even works, is because the implementation chosen for `getboolean` under the proxy's `get` is the one from `MyConfig` instead of the original faulty  in `RawConfigParser`

Comment: Looking at the code, `RawConfigParser.get` already uses `_UNSET` as the default fallback. `SectionProxy.get` uses `None` though, and it provides an implementation of `getboolean` through some magic I haven't dissected that ends up calling its own `get` with the `None` fallback. I guess now I'm back to not understanding why your solution works :D

Comment: Oh, because you check if the returned value is equal to the passed in fallback value, while the original class only checks if it's equal to _UNSET, which it won't be when the proxy is involved! Ok, I'm getting there eventually.

Comment: @Kemp lol. I figured it out. In the proxy `init`, there is a loop doing `setattr` to all different getters back to the single `get` with a specific implementation (using `partial`). Then, in its turn, `get` calls that specific implementation that somewhere along the way calls the `RawConfigParser`'s `get`. I "injected" my own `getboolean` as the implementation passed to `get` for the `getboolean`